# Blazor CookieAuthentication witha dditional query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

My app is run in iframe inside other app that handles authorization and passes down auth cookie
my request looks like **https://myapp/resource?clientId=1234&transactionId=12345**
Bothth apps are on Azure.
Whenever I try to authenticate incoming messages they are missing query part of request

MY application setup looks like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Logger? logger = LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Debug("Init main");

    try
    {
        WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        //logging
        builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
        builder.Host.UseNLog();

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/";
                    options.EventsType = typeof(SecureCookieAuthenticationEvents);
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/access-denied";
                });

        builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();
        builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ConfigurationContext>();
        builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
                .AddPolicy("CookiePolicy", policy =>
                {
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new SecureCookieRequirement());
                });
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, SecureCookieAuthorizationHandler>();
        .
                .
                .
        builder.Services.AddScoped<SecureCookieAuthenticationEvents>();
        WebApplication app = builder.Build();

        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseMiddleware<CookieAuthenticationMiddleware>();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMiddleware<ReverseProxyMiddleware>();
        app.UseAntiforgery();

        app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

        app.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Error(e, "Program stopped bue to problem");
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        LogManager.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

and then in *CookieAuthenticationMiddleware*

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    this.logger.LogInformation("incoming claims:");
    foreach (Claim claim in context.User.Claims)
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation($"{claim.Type}:{claim.Value}");
    }
    if (context.User.Identity is { IsAuthenticated: false } || context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Anonymous))
    {
        string clientId = context.Request.Query["clientId"].FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
        string cookie = context.Request.Cookies["CPFCookie"] ?? "";
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("clientId", clientId),
                    new Claim("CPFCookie", cookie),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "SecureUser")
                };

        this.logger.LogInformation("new claims:");
        foreach (Claim claim in claims)
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation($"{claim.Type}:{claim.Value}");
        }
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        await context.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity)
        );
    }

    await this.next(context);
}
```

and finally in *SecureCookieAuthenticationEvents*

```
public override async Task SigningIn(CookieSigningInContext context)
{
    ClaimsPrincipal? user = context.Principal;
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value == "/_blazor"
        || user is null
        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FindFirstValue("CPFCookie"))
        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FindFirstValue("clientId")))
    {
        List<Claim> ac = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Anonymous, "true")
        };
        ClaimsIdentity anonymous = new(ac, context.Principal?.Identity?.AuthenticationType);
        context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(anonymous);
        return;
    }
    this.logger.LogInformation("SigningIn...");
    bool validated = this.ValidationLogic(context);
    this.logger.LogInformation($"{context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()}");
    this.logger.LogInformation($"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path}");
    IEnumerable<Claim> claims = user.Claims.Append(new Claim("CPFCookieValidated", validated.ToString()));
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new(claims, context.Principal?.Identity?.AuthenticationType);
    context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await base.SigningIn(context);
}
```

I tried various things to and this is my last iteration which works locally on my machine but if failing againg in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that issue was in *CookieAuthenticationMiddleware* as it was fired for **ALL** requests (including internal blazor communication) so even my user got authorized at some point it was immediately overwritten with ne blank user from internal call.
My current fix is to add to checks in middleware invocation:

1. If we have required claim already → skip auth
2. if request path contains '/app/' → create new ClaimsIdentity, set it to Claims Principal and try to auth.
   In retrospective, I would use custom header instead of app path, but the idea wouldn't change.
   I don't know if this is the Best solution, but it works. I suspect that MS will introduce a way at some point to fire middleware only for non-internal calls.